# WSL - error when i try to set the path of jdk inside IntellJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Good evening,

I have installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Now I'm trying to set the paths of jdk after installed IntelliJ. The paths is:

`C:\Users\afaie\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\lib\jvm\java-8-oracle`

But if I try to build the project the result is this:

```
Error:Cannot run program "C:\Users\afaie\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\lib\jvm\java-8-oracle\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\afaie\.IdeaIC2017.1\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 non è un'applicazione di Win32 valida
```

Are there possibility of resolution ??

Thanks

Comment: From the error you posted it looks like a 64 bit executable vs 32-bit issue. Did you try with 32 bit JDK? Is this "java-8-oracle" a executable file (.exe?)

Comment: No. "Java-8-oracle" is a directory. But I have tryed to set also the path of java 7..

Comment: No response !? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to install the java JDK again on Windows in order to correctly link it to IntelliJ. Windows apps cannot reference/access/modify linux files or programs due the two kernels being incompatible, thus making it impossible for you to access your WSL installation of JDK 8 from Windows. Refer to this link for more information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/